# What is the historical origin of Medusa?

Tags: mythohistory, medusa

I read a short paragraph on Medusa's wikipedia page about the myth representing a historical event.

> A number of early classics scholars interpreted the myth of the Medusa
>   as a quasi-historical - "based on or reconstructed from an event,
>   custom, style, etc., in the past", or "sublimated" memory of an
>   actual invasion.

As I understood it, a Joseph Campbell suggests a temple with priestesses wearing gorgon masks, essentially, was invaded by King Perseus' Hellenes around 13th century BC, which would have been Mycenaean Greece I guess.

Is there any more info of this? Is anything known about these ancient snake priestesses/godesses/religions? How far back could this go? Proto-Indo-European, even? Or was she just based on a very early greek goddess/cult that was discarded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Gorgoneion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gorgoneion) is a likely origin for the priestess masks. The practice of these amulets as aspects of the Mother Goddess dates back to the Neolithic Age. The [oldest Gorgon mask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sesklo#Sesklo_culture) is from [Greek Sesklo culture before 6000 BC](https://books.google.be/books?id=7DfI39EDbMcC&redir_esc=y), but they have been excavated in many places from Etruskia to the Black sea coast.

Answer (score 3):

Pausanias has a euhemeristic explanation about the myth in *Description of Greece*:

> Not far from the building in the market-place of Argos is a mound of
>   earth, in which they say lies the head of the Gorgon Medusa. I omit
>   the miraculous, but give the rational parts of the story about her.
>   After the death of her father, Phorcus, she reigned over those living
>   around Lake Tritonis, going out hunting and leading the Libyans to
>   battle. On one such occasion, when she was encamped with an army over
>   against the forces of Perseus, who was followed by picked troops from
>   the Peloponnesus, she was assassinated by night. Perseus, admiring her
>   beauty even in death, cut off her head and carried it to show the
>   Greeks.
>
> But Procles, the son of Eucrates, a Carthaginian, thought a different
>   account more plausible than the preceding. It is as follows. Among the
>   incredible monsters to be found in the Libyan desert are wild men and
>   wild women. Procles affirmed that he had seen a man from them who had
>   been brought to Rome. So he guessed that a woman wandered from them,
>   reached Lake Tritonis, and harried the neighbours until Perseus killed
>   her; Athena was supposed to have helped him in this exploit, because
>   the people who live around Lake Tritonis are sacred to her.

<sub>[Paus.
2.21.5 and 2,21,6](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.01.0160:book=2:chapter=21)</sub>